# library resolve to a path with no project.properties file

Tags: android, ant, jenkins, actionbarsherlock

I'm having trouble building my project with Jenkins and referencing the Sherlock project library.

I can build the project with ant on my local system. The problem seems to be referencing the Sherlock library on the build server.

I pass an environment variable to ant with the relative path to the Sherlock library project:

```
android.library.reference.1=../../buildlibraries/androidlibraries/sherlock/library
```

I'm getting this error.

```
**BUILD FAILED**
/SDK/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:595: 
The following error occurred while executing this line:
/SDK/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:571: 
../../buildlibraries/androidlibraries/sherlock/library resolve to a path with 
no project.properties file for project /Users/Jenkins/buildlibraries/androidlibraries/sherlock/library
```

I checked and a project.properties file does exist at that location.

It has these properties:

```
android.library=true
# Project target.
target=android-14
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same thing happen to me just now.  I use both a Windows and Mac to develop with.  I watne d to test my project on both platforms.  It built just fine on my Windows machine, but broke on my Mac.  When I looked at my project.properties in my Android application (not library projects) on the Mac, I saw that my library projects were referenced this way:

```
android.library.reference.1=LibraryProjects\\my_lib_project
```

I changed it to the line below, and it worked just fine!

```
android.library.reference.1=LibraryProjects/my_lib_project
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue by editing and checking in the project.properties file with the same property: `android.library.reference.1=../../buildlibraries/androidlibraries/sherlock/library`

I'm not sure why it works. Why would ant care if the property is passed in by Jenkins vs. declared in the project's property file?

Now I have two paths in my project.properties file: one for a local build and one for the build on Jenkins.

Comment: where did you add the project.properties file?

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  No idea why you can't pass it in through Jenkins unfortunately :\

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with error *../google-play-services_lib resolve to a path with no project.properties file for project*. It has to work in Jenkins CI (Cloudbees), so no manual project.properties editing.

My solution was to replace `android update lib-project --path ...` with ugly but working `echo "android.library.reference.1=../../../..$ANDROID_HOME/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib" >> project.properties` in Jenkins shell command.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I hadn't downloaded the google play services package using the `android` tool.  When I checked my android sdk directory ($ANDROID_HOME) there was no "$ANDROID_HOME/extras/google" folder.

I fixed this by running `android` and downloading "Google Play services" found in the extras section.