# Problem in building pygame apk (project.properties file error)

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, pygame, apk

I am creating a game for Android using pygame and pgs4a. When I run `android.py build mygame release`
it throws this error :

```
Updating build files.  

Updated project.properties
Updated local.properties
Added file F:\pgs4a-master\build.xml
Updated file F:\pgs4a-master\proguard-project.txt

Creating assets directory.


Packaging internal data.

Listing private ...
Listing private\include ...
Listing private\include\python2.7 ...
Listing private\lib ...
Listing private\lib\PIL ...
Listing private\lib\android ...
Compiling private\lib\android\__init__.py ...
Compiling private\lib\android\apk.py ...
Compiling private\lib\android\mixer.py ...
Listing private\lib\encodings ...
Listing private\lib\json ...
Listing private\lib\pygame ...
Listing private\lib\pygame\threads ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7 ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\bsddb ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\compiler ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\config ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\distutils ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\distutils\command ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\email ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\email\mime ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\encodings ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\hotshot ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\importlib ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\json ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\lib-dynload ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\logging ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\multiprocessing ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\multiprocessing\dummy ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\plat-linux3 ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\pydoc_data ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\site-packages ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\site-packages\android ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\site-packages\jnius ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\site-packages\pygame ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\site-packages\pygame\threads ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\sqlite3 ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\sqlite3\test ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\unittest ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\wsgiref ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\xml ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\xml\dom ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\xml\etree ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\xml\parsers ...
Listing private\lib\python2.7\xml\sax ...
Listing private\lib\sqlite3 ...
Listing mygame ...
Compiling mygame\rotating_cube.py ...

I'm using Ant to build the package.

Buildfile: F:\pgs4a-master\build.xml

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at F:\pgs4a-master\android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MYCUbe-1.0
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-pre-clean:

clean:

BUILD FAILED
F:\pgs4a-master\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:459: ../../google-play-services_lib resolve to a path with no project.properties file for project F:\pgs4a-master

Total time: 3 seconds
```

I have absolutely no idea how to proceed further. I know that it has something to do with path of project.properties file. Even searching on internet for similar problem didn't help me.Can anyone tell me how to edit the `project.properties` file. Many thanks in advance!

**A request:**

If somebody has already completed a project using pgs4a it can really help me if you could provide the example of the code directory location, the contents of the `project.properties` file and other relevant details about the project. I will edit my files and locations accordingly!. I would be very grateful.

**Note:**
F:\pgs4a-master\mygame is folder containing python script `rotating_cube.py'

**Additional Info:**

My existing `project.properties` file in directory pgs4a-master (outside mygame directory) reads

```
target=android-19 
android.library.reference.1=../../google-play-services_lib
```

The path to my `google-play-services_lib` folder is

```
pgs4a-master/android-sdk/extras/google/google-play-services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
```

which also contains a `project.properties` file which reads:

```
target=android-10 
android.library=true
```

Comment: What's in `F:\pgs4a-master\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml` at line 459?

Comment: It is a build.xml file , it is usual for every pgs4a project. And I don't know which line 459 it is referring to ; maybe of android.py or something else..

Comment: You should probably open that xml and check that line and see what it expects. I'm trying to troubleshoot here without prior knowledge, and that feels like a good starting step :) In particular, I'm curious if that line points out project.properties or the plays-services lib.

Comment: Really Thanks,at least someone is interested!  Okay ,I checked the line459 which says:`<getlibpath library FolderPathOut="project.library.folder.path" />`.   But I am unable to figure out what it points to..

Comment: I'm guessing that's a variable/placeholder that gets replaced by another part of the config/instruction set. `project.library.folder.path` probably points to a faulty location where there is no `project.properties`. Or the lack of `project.properties` is creating the error because `project.library.folder.path` can't be replaced. I'm to unfamiliar with magical build chains to help you I think. `grep -rnw ./ project.library.folder.path`? ^^

Comment: I'm on windows so grep doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956199/library-resolve-to-a-path-with-no-project-properties-file

Comment: I have tried these but didn't work for me. I am unable to figure out what path should I edit

Comment: looks like a simple path quotes problem. "" and '' and `` The OS you are using is important.

Comment: Using Windows 10 @JonGoodwin

Comment: **"I'm on windows so grep doesn't work"** you can use UNIX tools on Windows (I have for 20 years) some examples, [git bash](https://gitforwindows.org/) , [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), [How to Install and Use the Linux Bash Shell on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/)

Comment: But the problem is what to do after I install Linux

Comment: There is `grep` for Windows in [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html). It is easier to install it than `cygwin` or Linux. But I was using it long time ago with Windows XP and I don't know if it works with Windows 10 (now I use only Linux). There is also [Linux subsystem in Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) - maybe it has grep.

Comment: Have you ever managed to build or run the project before? I would like to understand if your Android SDK environment is correctly setup, because your build errors indicate that the Android SDK paths located inside your project which is quite strange in terms of android development.

Comment: It is the first time I am trying to build a project.

Comment: The project.properties file in directory pgs4a-master (outside mygame directory)reads `target=android-19 android.library.reference.1=../../google-play-services_lib  `

Comment: The path to my google-play-services_lib folder is pgs4a-master/android-sdk/extras/google/google-play-services/libproject/google-play-services_lib which also contains a project.properties file which reads: `target=android-10 android.library=true `

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your Android SDK environment that is required to build the android app is not correctly setup or too new to do it.

Here is a step by step guide in order to start with **PGS4A** https://possiblywrong.wordpress.com/2012/06/16/python-on-android/

If I get it right you are trying to build this github repository https://github.com/duducosmos/pgs4a which is some module or example for using play-services and ads in a python-android application. The problem there is that the reference to play-services lib `../../google-play-services_lib` is not correct.
Changing that to `android-sdk/extras/google/google-play-services/libproject/google-play-services_lib` may solve this error.

Generally, the solution you are trying to build is based on Android tools that used 4-5 years ago. Eclipse with Android ADT plugin and `ant` build tool.

In order to make this work you may have to download those versions if there are somewhere available. Google dropped this support since 2016. So I would suggest you to try a different way because even you resolve that build errors with play services the output most probably will stuck in some incompatibilty problem or will not be able to run on new android devices.

To provide you some suggestion in order to continue you can check [**this**](https://towardsdatascience.com/tools-to-run-python-on-android-9060663972b4) article.

I've done some checking for you and the first 3 suggestions:

- BeeWare
- Chaquopy
- Kivy

All provide support newer Android SDK/NDK tools, so at least you will be able to find some support on them.

Checking a bit into them the Kivy looks to be more close to `pygame` as it one of it's dependencies.

You can check these sites:

- https://pythonprogramming.net/kivy-application-development-tutorial/
- https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debug-android
- https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/

but there get through the article as it contains extra details for android game development/debugging.

Comment: Many Thanks for the answer! I will try and see how it goes

Comment: An important question? Does Beeware really support pygame? I searched but couldn't find answer. Instead they are using 'toga'

Comment: Cannot tell... searching for "pygame and android" I've dropped into kivy which is the 3rd recomentation in the article. Android SDK/NDK support look good on this one as well. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I have tried kivy,it has pygame as dependency but is totally different from pygame. Pygame can't be developed on kivy

Comment: A final link that I dropped into https://pygame-catalin.blogspot.com/2013/08/working-with-pygame-subset-for-android.html it may help on the original problem but has some tips on building it.